# Create custom base URL for ID number

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, url-rewriting

In either Internet Explorer or Firefox, I would like to be able to type something short (i.e. `go ###`), and have it automcatiicaly change the `go` to a full prefix web address (i.e. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=). Is there a way to do this in either browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item is called "SearchUrl"

They are saved in the registry, along with a list of translations for special characters.

An example, using your request:

Create a `.reg` file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchUrl\kb]
@="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=%s"
":"="%3A"
```

This will register the keyword **kb** - the *%s* is the placeholder for the string you supply.
It also knows that when you type a `:` in the string that it should be substituted by `%3A` in the URL to ensure it is passed correctly.

Other common substitutions could include:

```
" "="+"
" "="%20"
"#"="%23"
"&"="%26"
"?"="%3F"
"+"="%2B"
"="="%3D"
```

Note you can only have one definition for each character, so in the above list, you would have to decide if a space should be translated to *%20* or *+*

If you wanted other shortcuts, you could add them in place of the *kb*, and produce a list of special shortcuts - [this site](http://www.commandline.co.uk/searchurl/) has several you can choose from. (go, find and ? have special meaning, so cannot be used)

To actually use the shortcut, use the **address bar** (shortcut is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> ) and type your text in there, e.g. `kb 198279` takes you to *Managing Exchange Server 2007: How to Configure Storage Quotas for a Mailbox Database*

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to make "go" a hotstring. You could use `IfWinActive` to make the hotstring only work in your browsers.

Sample code:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class IEFrame                   ; for IE
:O:go::http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=   ; the "O" omits the trailing space
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1        ; for Chrome
:O:go::http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=   ; the "O" omits the trailing space
```

Comment: What if I want to type "goto"? Will the go just expand automatically, or recognize that it's just by itself?

Comment: AutoHotKey supports either option. The default is to look for the hotstring followed by a space, comma, etc. But you can also tell it to replace without waiting.